# How to click on a dynamic link using Selenium Webdriver + Java in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-headless

**I am trying to click a dynamic link with Selenium where when I run the tests in GUI they are perfectly fine because I am using a method where I copy the link from the clipboard but in headless mode the usage of the clipboard is not possible.

I am using several options but so far I haven't been successful. Any hint I would appreciate it

```
    WebElement dynamicLinkElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-test-share-portal-url]"));
    dynamicLinkElement.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");

    ArrayList<String> tabs1 = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs1.get(1));

    String dynamicLink = getLinkFromClipboard();
    driver.get(dynamicLink);
    Thread.sleep(5000);

    int retryCount = 0;

    // Define the maximum number of retries
    int maxRetries = 10; // Adjust this value as needed

    // Define the URL to check for "not found"

    System.out.println(driver.getCurrentUrl());

    // Retry until the URL is no longer "not found" or the maximum retries are reached
    while (driver.getCurrentUrl().contains("not-found") && (retryCount < maxRetries)) {
        // Wait for 5 seconds before the next retry
        // Refresh the page to try again
        driver.get(dynamicLink);

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Increment the retry count
        retryCount++;
    }

    ArrayList<String> tabs0 = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs0.get(0));

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

---

```
 WebElement dynamicLinkElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button[data-test-share-portal-url]"));
    dynamicLinkElement.click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    // Open a new tab using JavaScript
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open()");

    ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
    driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); // Switch to the new tab


    // Parse the HTML content of the new tab to extract the dynamic link
    String dynamicLink = extractDynamicLinkFromPageSource(driver.getPageSource());

    if (dynamicLink != null) {
        driver.get(dynamicLink);
        Thread.sleep(5000);

        // Rest of your retry and assertion logic
    } else {
        // Handle the case where dynamicLink is not found
    }

    Thread.sleep(3000);
}

private String extractDynamicLinkFromPageSource(String pageSource) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(pageSource);

    // Modify this selector based on your actual HTML structure
    Elements linkElements = document.select("a[data-test-share-portal-url]");

    if (!linkElements.isEmpty()) {
        Element linkElement = linkElements.first();
        String dynamicLink = linkElement.attr("href");
        return dynamicLink;
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: At which line are you exactly stuck?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium I am stuck at the line where I have to get the link from the clipboard which becomes unavailable in headless mode.

String dynamicLink = getLinkFromClipboard();
    driver.get(dynamicLink);

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer!
While you work in headless mode your clipboard becomes unavailable, so I created a method to copy the link and one a new tab.